# django-tastypie foreign key trouble

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a post model and a postImage model:

```
class PostImage(models.Model):
    post =  models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="images")
    # @@@@ figure out a way to have image folders per user...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order = models.IntegerField()
```

I have created tastypie resources for both:

```
class PostImageResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = PostImage.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'postImage'


class PostResource(ModelResource):
    images = fields.ForeignKey(PostImageResource, 'images', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Post.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'post'
```

When I try to browse to `api/v1/post/?format=json` I get the following error:

```
The object '' has an empty attribute 'image' and doesn't allow a default or null value.
```

**I don't have any PostImages yet.**

If I get rid of the `images = fields.foreignKey` line in `PostResource`, it works. If I browse to `api/v1/postImage/?format=json`, no error is shown, just an empty collection.

Comment: Have you checked that all of your PostImage objects have populated the `image` field?

Comment: I don't have any PostImage objects yet. I want to be able to have Posts without images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class PostResource(ModelResource):
    images = fields.OneToManyField(PostImageResource, 'images', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Post.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'post'
```

------- EDITED -------

Hmm...

In Your model:

```
class PostImage(models.Model):
    post =  models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="images")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order = models.IntegerField()
```

Note null=True and blank=True.

Comment: fields.ForeignKey is the same as fields.OneToManyField

Comment: @alexBrand no. ForeignKey extends ToOneField and OneToManyField extends ToManyField =]